# Spring destroy temporary objects after defined period of time

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc form that uses a kaptcha in order to prove that the user is a human and not a machine. After entering the requested information, a random value is generated which must be available in the servlet context for 120 seconds. The user could take that value and entered it as a key from another another application (add-on) in order to complete the registration process. That is the reason why that random value must have a global scope and not session scope. If no request has been received by another application during those 120 seconds i would like to destroy that random string/object. I am looking here for the best practices i.e. one way i can think of is  been implemented in Spring is the following example an example.

1) create a collection that can hold multiple obeject of that random value type

2) save the radom value in the application context (not session)

3) define those object with a scope of global-session

4) when a request come in get the HttpServletRequest extract the value sent by the user

5) iterate trouh teh application context and if such values is found proceed further if not end the process immediately.

now that might theoretically work but how do i make sure that the value that i have generated in step 1  is destroyed after 120 second if no request object came within the defined period of type i.e. 120 seconds. I want to be sure that the memory freed.

What would be the best practice in order to implement such construct within Spring. Shell i use TaskScheduler or something else? Is the best place to store that random value the application context?

Comment: That's exactly what sessions or maybe databases are for.

Comment: Why do you want to use servlet context for that (shared amont any session) instead of simply putting the random value in *session* and compare it on next request (of same session ...)  ?

Comment: the point is that i can not put it in the session as that random value should be then POSTed from another application i.e. that could be another session, another PC, thus i need it in the global servlet context i.e. that should not be a session scoped value

Comment: Bart, this should not be placed in the session as i mentioned before  that value should be accessible from any session, and i would like that object that hold that random value to be in the memory and not the database thus making things a little more faster